# Calculate distance using GPS : How to consider accuracy differences

Tags: algorithm, math, gps, geometry

I am developing a mobile application which calculates distance based on the GPS. I am using the following haversine function to calculate distance.

```
var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
      var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
      var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
      var a = 
        Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
      var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
      var d = R * c; // Distance in km
```

My concern is regarding how to handle the different location accuracy values.

ie, first I get a location with an accuracy of 30m and then I get a location with an accuracy of 150m.

*To get a better distance calculation, which location do I need to consider/avoid for distance calculation? Or how can I adjust for these accuracy differences in my calculation using above formula?*

I am hoping for advice from experts.

Comment: Calculation of dLat and dLon is wrong as point maybe on equator and on
north Pole. eg when delta is same but in north pole distance 0 but in equator is big. To find disatance search x,y,z of points and calculate arc angle and only after calculate distance. Resume: problem not in accuracy.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I asking about to get best estimate when of distance between points. I continuously tracking the gps locations for calculate the distance.During this period how i  manage the accuracy difference to  get best estimate.

Comment: @Толя do you mean anti podal points? The above haversine formula principally works, but there are exceptions

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark absolutley not correct. GPS receivers must report in real time. so they cannot optimize their filtering to distance calculations. Each GPS application, in his case distance needs it own filtering. (above the GPS receivers internal filtering)

Comment: @Ajmal if you search here on SO, there are answers how to do distance calcuation with inaccurate GPS signals. Just search harder. There are simple solutions, which works with the most basic school mathematics. (the haversien is then the  most complex part ) ;-)

Comment: @AlexWien you got the point.. Thanks .. :) If you already know about any links/sites that will be helpfull please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the know formulas like yours, or the built in on your smart phones API is acurate enough for small distances like GPS location to next location distance calculation.

But the main thing is not the distance formula.
You need to filter the GPS positions, you should not simply calculate the distance from one location to next.

Otherwise, especially at low speed movement you will sum up a zig zag line of inacurate GPS trajetory.

Comment: thats completely right, and mostly common used is a Kalman filter. There are dozen implementations available for mostly any language. That's fast and efficient way to filter gps tracks. If you would want to go even more accurate way you should link your track with actual cartography to match a route, then you get even better accuracy by removing 'cutted' corners etc.

Comment: @evilruff yes and no: if you link with cartography then distances are wrong in corners, a car drives shorter way, than a 90° street crossing which is modelled in cartzography as a 90° angle, But the real car drives a curved shorter than the 90° angle. And things get worse if you drive on a road not on the map, but nearby ....

Comment: i agree, that's what I wrote, it's not that easy as it's asked.. I was developing ECS/ECDIS systems for mostly 5 years.. people just oftenly not see backgrounds on their problems hoping that there is a magic formula somewhere, which is not true.. it depends on a task first of all.. because for example if we are talking about VTS of FleetManagement you could have have pretty large distances in between GPS samples (saying we are talking about trucks driving thousands of miles).. and then you should also apply things similar to 'dead reckoning' to make an estimations on actual distance..

Comment: @evilruff what ere ECS/ECDIS systems?

Comment: they indeed can be, and solutions are known, BUT they work well on spherical coordinates until you stay within certain geographical location, then you can get very good estimation. but if for example it's a marine fleet management you cant escape that easy...

Comment: ECS = Electronic Cartography Systems ECDIS - Electronic Chart Display and Information System.

Comment: yes, for marine, its a bit more complex, traversing the datum limit is error prone and  in the past he navigation system of two jet fighter chrahsed while traversing the daum limit. (However the haversine formula above should work in the situations,)

Comment: well, conclusion.. if it's about filtering best option I would think of is pushing incoming data into stack (let's say they coming every second) and then made a distance calculation based on all previous points excluding last one but after Kalman filtering once in 10-15 seconds.. and still I would consider to use rectangular coordinates..

Comment: hm, well do you think that WGS84 should be transformed to the ellipsoid that is best for a particular country? There are countries like Italy the don't use WGS84 even not in UTM. The use UTM ED50. converting to rectangular may have advanatage when using a filter like Kalman

Comment: Italy
ETRF89
    UTM Zone 31N
    UTM Zone 32N
    UTM Zone 33N
    UTM Zone 34N
ETRS89
    UTM Zone 31N
    UTM Zone 32N
    UTM Zone 33N
    UTM Zone 34N
European 1950
    UTM Zone 31N
    UTM Zone 32N
    UTM Zone 33N
    UTM Zone 34N
Monte Mario
    Italy 1
    Italy 2
Monte Mario (Rome)
    Italy 1
    Italy 2
WGS72
    UTM Zone 31N
    UTM Zone 32N
    UTM Zone 33N
    UTM Zone 34N
WGS84
    UTM Zone 31N
    UTM Zone 32N
    UTM Zone 33N
    UTM Zone 34N

Comment: many countries using own ellipsoids for different (mostly military) reasons, but you still can use the one you prefer and make proper rectangular transformations

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it's not that easy.. As being mentioned in comment 'distance' in that respect can be a lot of different things depending on what your coordinates are. There are several Earth elliptical 'models' so you should consider this then writing your algorithm.

In case of GPS it's WGS84 projection. if you need fast and efficient solution take a look on Proj4 library which incorporate all this things inside itself and has bindings to almost everything.

Best way to go is to convert your coordinated into meters (but then you should take zone in consideration) and then make a calculation using rectangular coordinates.  you might want to have a look in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19760/how-do-i-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-given-a-distance-and-latitude-longitude). It proposes several ways of solving it.

inaccurate, but will do a job on non extreme locations and small distance. (never use it any any proper navigation software), but..

```
10001.965729km = 90 degrees
1km = 90/10001.965729 degrees = 0.0089982311916 degrees
10km = 0.089982311915998 degrees
```

Comment: any explanation about -1?

Comment: You did not understand his question. And your answer does not help him. GPS location are WGS84, you dont need proj4 to transform for his task.

Comment: WGS84 still has zones, which should be taken in consideration if you want to make proper rectangular transformation. Of course you can rely on certain assumptions like certain distance in one degree but that's very approximate. And you will have different results depending on where on a planet you are measuring..

Comment: WGS84 has no zones, UTM WGS84 has zones. UTM is used to project into the plane, for varoius reasons. But he can calculate spherical. But this all does not help. The main point is GPS filtering.

Comment: true, you are right about UTM.. but you should agree that there are two 'steps' - 1) filtering and 2) measuring.. and simple spherical calculations give you bigger mistakes then rectangular conversions

Comment: 1) ok, but 2) I dont think so. The distance between two location are not more than 70m, and for that every formula works. Things differ at high distances, but then all other influences have more impact: 2D distances as usual vs. 3D distances (mountain). When road not plane,

Comment: about 2) i dont think that for small distances it's so easy.. if it's about distance from my to my neighbours house.. I would completely agree because it's single calculation, BUT let's say your formula makes a stable absolute mistake (which I believe not even absolute but also has relative part)... then at the end of the day totals will accumulate this, so for algorithms where you make a sum of small measurements its even more critical to have calculation on each step as precise as possible.

Comment: But especiallay at polar regions the spherical formulas are well accurate, and the rectangualr does not work well

Comment: hope nobody going to navigate with iphone in his hands around north pole =)

Comment: but you coming to point I meant initially, it's not only about HOW to calculate or MEASURE something, it's about WHAT FOR you need those numbers, which CALCULATION ERROR you can accept, and HOW you going to process them later on, so you can think of how this CALCLUTAION MISTAKE will affect other parts of your system

Comment: you can even think of skipping some points you get from GPS in case HDOP/VDOP is crap.. or at least take values from then with care